# Rigging is affecting both arms

Tags: modeling, mesh, rigging, mirror, pose-mode

I've recently tried rigging for the first time, and it seems to be working fine, with one exception. When I change the right arm, it effects the left, but not vice versa. This also is not a problem with the legs, both move independently just fine, it's specifically the arms, and I'm not sure why. I made sure to check through the weight paint to make sure that the right isn't controlling the left, and it wasn't. I even made sure to subtract it from the left anyways just in case it wasn't showing up. Mirroring doesn't seem to be on, so I'm not sure what the problem is. Here's the blend file
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KXs7VfyT4T3ggIR00GHaK-14M0KcGKzw/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please use the site dedicated to BSE for sharing files: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/. Once uploaded paste the provided link here.

Answer (score 0):

Bone.008 does not respect naming conventions for mirroring:

[image]

Names on right part should finish with ".R" or ".Right" (for instance) to be recognized when parenting to bones.

In more details, [the documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/armatures/bones/editing/naming.html#naming-conventions):

> Examples of valid separators:
>
> ```
> (nothing): handLeft –> handRight
>
> “_” (underscore): hand_L –> hand_R
>
> “.” (dot): hand.l –> hand.r
>
> “-” (dash): hand-l –> hand-r
>
> ” ” (space): hand LEFT –> hand RIGHT
> ```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it. I didn't see that stray bone